# I am trying to make an aside menu with <ul>

Tags: html, css

I am making a little page as a project for school (don't mind content, it's in Polish). I have tried deleting CSS and it worked, but the look of it was just awful.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

header img {
  width: 350px;
  /* Zmienić odpowiednio */
  height: auto;
}

content {
  margin-left: 500px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

aside {
  min-height: 110vh;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  width: 2;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
}

aside ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

aside ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 230px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="zdjecia/diablologo.png" alt="Diablo Logo">
</header>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="bocz1.html">Pow</a>
      <li><a href="bocz2.html">Powrót do strony głównej</a>
        <li><a href="bocz3.html">Powrótony głównej</a>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

I tried making `<a>` as a button but still nothing. I just want to open second page linked to a specific `<a href>`. The link to the page is valid; it worked without CSS.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain the problem more clearly. Is the problem that your links don't **look** as you want them to, or that they don't **work** as you want them to?

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumption is the reason you're having issues with your links is due to an invalid URI path. If you double check that the page you're trying to go to is being linked to properly since the CSS you have here shouldn't interfere with the link.

As an example, I've recreated your code and added completely different links to illustrate my point.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

header img {
  width: 350px; /* Zmienić odpowiednio */
  height: auto;
}

content {
  margin-left: 500px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

aside {
  min-height: 110vh;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  width: 2;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
}

aside ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

aside ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 230px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="zdjecia/diablologo.png" alt="Diablo Logo">
</header>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Pow</a>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Powrót do strony głównej</a>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Powrótony głównej</a>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap for this type of nav.

```
between html head tags

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    enter code here
body
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu example
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
   body

For more options check out https://getbootstrap.com/
```